# Discard stderr in start-process

Tags: shell, process

I'm using `start-process` to run mplayer and when playing videos I get a ton of output to stderr from "vdp_...". On the command line I usually just 2>/dev/null but `start-process` runs it directly without a shell. (I tried `start-process-shell-command` but it simply does not work at all). `call-process` lets you provide a list for separate stdout and stderr but it seems `start-process` does not. I don't see an option to mplayer to inhibit the output. If only there were a way to do with `start-process` what you can do with `call-process`. Is there some way I'm not seeing to do this?

Comment: The second argument in `start-process` is the output buffer's name, which can be `nil` to suppress the output buffer entirely.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, I still want to see stdout since I grab that time stamp at times. That all works great if it's just music, only the video produces the junk to stderr.

Comment: In that case, you can set up a filter to only print the strings or portions of strings that you want to see -- you'll need to identify either the stuff you want to see or the stuff you don't want to see and set up some rules -- e.g., with regexp and string= etc.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html

Comment: Thanks lawlist, I look forward to playing with filters. I might even try that for this project since it seems to make sense for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an emacs forum, but maybe the simplest thing to do is to write a simple shell script that filters *stderr*. For example in file `nostderr.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh 
$@ 2>/dev/null
exit $?
```

And then run that in your `start-process`.

Comment: In fact this is what the docstring says as well: `If you want to separate standard output from standard error, invoke
the command through a shell and redirect one of them using the shell
syntax`

Comment: Yes, that's one of the work-arounds I'd thought of, but good catch on finding that in the docstring. For that I'll give you the win. What I ended up doing was just searching further back and found what I wanted from the stdout. But in cases when what you are searching for cannot be separated from stderr, this is probably best.

Comment: As for this being an emacs forum, your suggestion was perfectly apropos to the problem which involves command lines.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs 25 introduced the function `make-process` for creating asynchronous processes, which is lower-level than `start-process`.  In particular, you can separate `stderr` from `stdout` by passing a buffer or pipe as the function's `:stderr` keyword argument.  For example:

```el
(make-process :name "mplayer"
              :buffer (generate-new-buffer "*mplayer out*")
              :command '("mplayer" "/path/to/video")
              :connection-type 'pipe
              :stderr (generate-new-buffer "*mplayer err*"))
```

The standard output and error streams of `mplayer` will now appear in buffers with names like `*mplayer out*` and `*mplayer err*`, respectively.

See [`(info "(elisp) Asynchronous Processes")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html) for more information.

Comment: I have tried to replace start-process with make-process but I keep getting errors and am unfortunately not well-versed in elisp... an example might be nice here

Comment: @Xerus Done. What kind of errors are you getting?